# Facebook sdk authentication to check if user is a college student?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The application that I'm making will be specifically targeted towards college students. I know that the Facebook sdk has the ability to access a users school/university information, but how could I implement that when a user authenticates the app using Facebook?

To give you a better idea of what I'm looking for:

User opens the app
User presses login with Facebook
The login/authentication process via Facebook will check to see if that person is attending a university through their profile information. 
If they are it will log them in.

How could I go about implementing this? Or is there a better way to check for if a user is a university student?

I am making this application for iOS and will also be utilizing parse for the backend of the application.

Comment: Did you read the graph API docs to see if you can get the information?

Comment: I did read the docs and have access to the college information, but I'm not sure exactly as to how I could implement that check as apart of the authentication process.

Comment: Add details of how you are doing the login to the question (Social framework / parse login controller / FB SDK).

Comment: Not every student might have that info set in their profile – so would you want to _force_ them to update that to use your app …?

Comment: @CBroe I did think about that fact, but I don't know of any better way to check whether or not they are a college student. Do you have any other idea as to how I could do it besides for Facebook?